# how do i take a user input for the number of sides in an equilateral polygon and have turtle draw it

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

here's what i have so far but it's not working close to well. I'm trying to take a user input for the number of sides in an equilateral polygon and have turtle draw it

```
import turtle 

window=turtle.Screen()

draw=turtle.Turtle()

def poly(sides):
    '''draws equilateral polygon with x number of sides
    '''

    draw.color('red')
    draw.pensize(5)

    for i in sides:
        draw.forward(150)
        draw.left(90)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Two ways you could go about doing this.

The non-efficient way:

```
sides = input('Enter a "." for every side you want: ')
sides = list(sides)
```

That would split each "." into a new item in sides, which is now a list. The better way would be probably what you are looking for, which is where the user just enters the number of sides they want:

```
sides = int( input('Enter number of sides: ') )

for side in range(sides):
    draw()
```

Range takes a range of numbers does something with it. For example:

```
>>> for num in range(6):
...    print num
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

> > [More on the range function](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range)

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this code, there were two issues.

The first error was with the for loop. For loops cannot iterate across integers. So if you want to run a for loop 3 times, you can't just pass 3 to the for loop. The standard way around this is to use the `range()` function. To do so you can merely pass it the variable and it will create a list object that has objects numbering from 0 to (x - 1). For example, if I called `range(5)` I would get an array like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. So the code would look like

```
    for i in range(sides):
```

and that'll iterate properly.

There is a second error, but I won't tell you how to fix that, so that you can try and figure it out. If you can't figure out how to draw the sides properly, comment on my response and I'll edit this post.